# iTunes constantly freezing on download

Tags: itunes, network-shares

Well... nuts.

I got my iTunes libraries copied over from my Macbook and my desktop PC to a SMB share on a network server on my LAN.  Got everything merged, and other than an occasional pause/hiccup it was working pretty well.  I'm starting iTunes from a shortcut on the network drive  I have a couple seasons worth of tv episodes left to download, both SD & HD, purchased from the iTunes store.  Problem is... now whenever I try to open iTunes and watch an episode stored on the server share, it freezes up.  If I let it check for downloads... it freezes.  If I start watching an episode... it freezes.  Sometimes I don't even get that far... and it freezes.  I mean 'freezes' as in no movement of the download bar, no response to mouse clicks or keystrokes, and shown in Task Manager on the PC as 'Not Responding'.  I have to kick it loose and restart it... and then it freezes again.  I've gone into the Preferences and made sure it was set to *not* automatically download content from the store, etc. but it still keeps trying... and freezing.

I'm at my wits end here... I spent an awful lot of time (better part of a week) getting everything copied over to the network drive (household network is combination of 802.11g and HomePlugAV) and now I can't watch my stuff, or even do anything at all with iTunes.

Help!

Monte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two iTunes instances are open at the same time, using the same library file, bad things happen. You need to have a way to make sure it's not open on both PC and Mac. My suggestion is to leave it open on the PC, then have the Mac use Home Sharing (with a 'local' library file) and stream that way. When you add new music, you'll have to do it from the PC. There is a way to select between multiple libraries when iTunes starts, so you could use a local library and Home Sharing most of the time, but still start up using the shared library whenever you need to add music. To select, hold on `Option` on the Mac, or `Alt` on Windows.

Either way, make sure only one iTunes instance is using the SMB library at any time.

Comment: Actually, I hadn't gotten around to setting up the Macbook again after copying things over, as apparently I need separate library files for Mac & PC (due to different paths stored in therein).  So only one machine, PC, accessing the library at any one time.  I copied some of the library files and episodes back to the PC and restarted iTunes running locally off the updated library there, and it still hangs...